# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #142: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

currently I'm learning android developing, and I have one problem with Textview and I haven't any idea how to solve it.

```
07-13 10:46:00.240 16541-16541/sabo.idocs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sabo.idocs, PID: 16541
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #142: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at sabo.idocs.main.menu.profile.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:82)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020053 a=-1 r=0x7f020053}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3014)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1220)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:173)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at sabo.idocs.main.menu.profile.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:82) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here my Textview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/change_icon2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/password_change_text"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view2"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp" />
```

And this is my fragment class:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private ImageView userAvatar;
private TextView userName;
private TextView passwordChange;
private EditText emailText;
private EditText mobilePhone;

private String path;

private OkHttpClient client;
private Request request;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private RelativeLayout profileLayout;
private User user;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View profile = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);

    profileLayout = (RelativeLayout)profile.findViewById(R.id.profile_layout);

    sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PROJECT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String userData = sharedPreferences.getString(SingletonConstants.USER, "");
    user = gson.fromJson(userData, User.class);

    userAvatar = (ImageView)profile.findViewById(R.id.user_avatar);
    userAvatar.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    userName = (TextView)profile.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    emailText = (EditText)profile.findViewById(R.id.email_json);
    mobilePhone = (EditText)profile.findViewById(R.id.mob_phone);
    passwordChange = (TextView)profile.findViewById(R.id.change_icon2);

    passwordChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfilePassword.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) profile.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container_profile);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_green_dark, android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, android.R.color.holo_orange_light);

    profileDefaults();
    onClick();
    return profile;
}
```

Yes, I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691683/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-87-error-inflating-class-t) but in my case it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: @drawable/arrow_right      check the arrow_right file in your drawable

Comment: @Raj I have this image in my drawable folder

Comment: Image type .png or .jpg or Webp format     ,because some times jpg fies corrupted this type of issue arise for me

Comment: I know about that problem with .jpg format image, my image format .png

Comment: Do you have a folder named `drawable-v21` if you have this remove image from that folder and put it in dpi folders.

Comment: I don't know, In TextView what is the use of this line?  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: yes I have drawable-21

Comment: Remove arrow_right from 21 and paste it in drawable-xdpi or simply drawable folder. The issue is  drawable-21 is not available in older versions.

Comment: @Raj i deleted this line

Comment: @sunilsunny okay, I will try it

Comment: textAlignment and Image drawable in Right Both are right side                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"     Change any one

Comment: @sunilsunny wow yeap it's work, thank you very much)

Comment: remove text alignment or textalignment ="left" and drawableright="image"       //   textalignment="end"   or drawableleft="image"

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is if you have an image in `drawable-21` it will not take as a drawable in older versions of Android.So you have to remove the image from that folder and move it to `drawble` or `dpi` folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the image from drawable folder to mipmap. This worked for me.